# Google Play Reject because Pushwoosh sdk collect installed applications

Tags: android, google-play, pushwoosh

I submitted an application to Google Play and it was rejected due to following reason:
Your application sends installed applications information to https://cp.pushwoosh.com/json/1.3/setAttributes without disclosure.

I do use Pushwoosh for push notification, I've been searching around to see if anyone has dealt with same problem but no luck. Hope I can find the anwser here.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Some time ago apps were approved after automatic tests, but now someone manually looks at your app and decides if it’s ok to pass it or rejects that. Google uses a mix between automated app testing and human reviewing to catch policy violations fast without impacting the time it takes to have an app published on Google Play

[Your app was rejected for violating Google’s policy – Now What?](http://www.androidb.com/2015/11/your-app-was-rejected-for-violating-googles-policy-now-what/)

Comment: Thank you. I tried contacting Pushwoosh team, once I have the answer I will update it here so anyone else can take advantage